# How to get legend to show in graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, stock, moving-average

Made a simple program to create exponential moving averages for a stock. Code below:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.style as style
import datetime as dt

yf.pdr_override()

style.use('ggplot')

startyear = 2019
startmonth = 1
startday = 1

start = dt.datetime(startyear, startmonth, startmonth)
end = dt.datetime.now()

stock = input('Enter stock ticker: ')

df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, end)

emasUsed = [3, 5, 8, 10, 13, 15, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 60]

for x in emasUsed:
    ema = x
    df['EMA_'+str(ema)] = df['Adj Close'].ewm(span=ema, adjust=True).mean()
    df['EMA_'+str(ema)].plot()

plt.show()
```

I want to graph the moving averages but cannot get the legend to show up unless I graph the EMAs on a separate line like this:

```
df[['EMA_3', 'EMA_5', 'EMA_8', etc...]].plot()
```

This is obviously a lot of work to do especially if I want to say add or change the EMAs that I want to get.

Is there any way to get the legend to show up without having to type in each EMA manually?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the axis prior to your plots, then use it to plot your legend. Call it after the plots are done and that's it.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.style as style
import datetime as dt

yf.pdr_override()

style.use('ggplot')

startyear = 2019
startmonth = 1
startday = 1

start = dt.datetime(startyear, startmonth, startmonth)
end = dt.datetime.now()

#stock = input('Enter stock ticker: ')
stock = 'SPY'

df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, end)

emasUsed = [3, 5, 8, 10, 13, 15, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 60]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8)) # get the axis and additionally set a bigger plot size

for x in emasUsed:
    ema = x
    df['EMA_'+str(ema)] = df['Adj Close'].ewm(span=ema, adjust=True).mean()
    df['EMA_'+str(ema)].plot()
legend = ax.legend(loc='upper left') # Here's your legend

plt.show()
```

And the result:

[image]